# Memory address calculation in "Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit"

Tags: c, memory, assembly, stack-overflow

I am reading "[Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?id=14&issue=49)"

In the section of "Buffer Overflows", I see this:

```
    0x8000490 <main>:       pushl  %ebp
    0x8000491 <main+1>:     movl   %esp,%ebp
    0x8000493 <main+3>:     subl   $0x4,%esp
    0x8000496 <main+6>:     movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
    0x800049d <main+13>:    pushl  $0x3
    0x800049f <main+15>:    pushl  $0x2
    0x80004a1 <main+17>:    pushl  $0x1
    0x80004a3 <main+19>:    call   0x8000470 <function>
    0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp
    0x80004ab <main+27>:    movl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
    0x80004b2 <main+34>:    movl   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
    0x80004b5 <main+37>:    pushl  %eax
    0x80004b6 <main+38>:    pushl  $0x80004f8
    0x80004bb <main+43>:    call   0x8000378 <printf>
    0x80004c0 <main+48>:    addl   $0x8,%esp
    0x80004c3 <main+51>:    movl   %ebp,%esp
    0x80004c5 <main+53>:    popl   %ebp
    0x80004c6 <main+54>:    ret
    0x80004c7 <main+55>:    nop
```

"We can see that when calling function() the RET will be 0x8004a8, and we
want to jump past the assignment at 0x80004ab.  The next instruction we want
to execute is the at 0x8004b2.  A little math tells us the distance is 8
bytes."

I don't get the answer here. 0x80004b2 - 0x80004ab = 7, right? Why the author says it is 8?
Do I miss any point here?

Answer (score 5):

I was wondering this as well. I can only think that aleph1 never actually tested that code because I am sure the offset should be 10 (0x80004b2 - 0x80004a8). I've also found this version of the article which corrects the original value to be 10.

http://www.cs.wright.edu/~tkprasad/courses/cs781/alephOne.html

Comment: I have another question, so it is not gonna execute '0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp' as well? Will that cause any trouble? Because seems like we lost track about esp. In this situation, I don't think it causes any troubles.. we are just occupying the 12 bytes in the stack which stores nothing. The stack can keep grow downward without any problems and finally we just replace esp by old ebp.